# convert API response to class object in C# by removing data type from response

Tags: c#, json

I am getting API response something like this

```
 {
    "results": [{
        "itemdescription": {
            "raw": "xyz"
        },
        "productcategory5": {
            "raw": "avx"
        },
        "productcategory6": {
            "raw": "DG"
        }
    }]
}
```

I am trying to convert this to class object using DeserializeObject

```
lObjJsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductVm>(lObjResponseData);
```

but in my VM I have to add extra property

```
[JsonProperty("raw")]
public string raw { get; set; }
```

How I can avoid this as if I convert my class object to json it will again have datatype property with every field .

my class code is below -

```
public class ProductAppSearchVm
{
 
    public MetaClass meta { get; set; }
    public List<ProductDetails> results { get; set; }

}

public class ProductProperty
{
    [JsonProperty("raw")]
    public string raw { get; set; } 
}

public class ProductDetails
{          
    public ProductProperty itemdescription{ get; set; }
    public ProductProperty productcategory5{ get; set; }
    public ProductProperty productcategory6{ get; set; }
}
```

any suggestion how can I have simple data like -

```
{
    "results": [{
            "itemdescription": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "productcategory5": "avx"
        },
        {
            "productcategory6": "DG"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "datatype property"? The `raw`-tag? Could you please provide your class also?

Comment: Can you post the full ProductVm properties?

Comment: yes @HimBromBeere raw tag , i added class property in post

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty yes added in post

Comment: You want itemdescription, productcategory5 and productcategory6 to be separate objects in the response?

Comment: Is it ok if the response is like { "itemdescription": "xyz", "productcategory5": "avx", "productcategory6": "DG" }? What ever you are expecting is not possible with the current classes.

Comment: seems like what you need is a mapper to convert from `ProductAppSearchVm` which is what you receive to another object of your like being `itemdescription` `string` instead of `ProductProperty`; but you will need to build that object.

Comment: @TiGreX i was thinking to use automapper  but yes i need to first convert json to above vm and then apply auto-mapper to generate different object , or is there any way direct i can do it ?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty response i m receiving from different api , i want to  map in simple class object.  for example instead of ProductProperty  i want to use string .

Comment: I know it's not helpful, but whoever designed the json didn't do a good job.  Is there any way you can change whatever system creates the json to output a better format?

Comment: @Neil its elastic app search api response  :)

Comment: any reason why you want three different objects instead of a single one with three properties?

Comment: @HimBromBeere is rightly said, the Json and class structures are not good. It could be optimized.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Sh.Imran  json structure i cant change as its coming from third part API  , due to class strutre its forced me to have extra class  ProductProperty , this is what i am trying to avoid how i can map json public string itemdescription{ get; set; } , instead of public ProductProperty itemdescription{ get; set; }

Comment: the question isn´t about where your data **comes from**, but **where it goes**? Does your client (to which you send your response) really expect the json in this weird format? Should your output really be `new { Itemdescription = ... }, new { ProductCatagory5 = ... }, new { ProductCategory6 = ... }`? Those are completely different classes, as they have compeletey different properties.

Comment: Your mentioned Json that getting from API response is not in correct format. Provide this the correct one

Comment: Your sample json response is is not properly structured. Missing end curly brace. Please give us the correct json to help you.

Comment: hi @HimBromBeere  , no i dont want to have raw tag for my client so i can do  the approach json -> vm -> another vm (without raw tag property ) , but i am trying to find out is there any way where i can direct map my json data to something like  -  string itemdescription{ get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

**Not yet sure performance wise. But for your desired output this might give you a hint.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonString = "{\"results\":[{\"itemdescription\":{\"raw\":\"xyz\"},\"productcategory5\":{\"raw\":\"avx\"},\"productcategory6\":{\"raw\":\"DG\"}}]}";
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductDetails>(jsonString);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetFormattedJson);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ProductDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, ProductProperty>> Detail { get; set; }

    public string GetFormattedJson
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(",", Detail.Select(dic => "{\"results\":[" + string.Join(",", dic.Select(pp => $"{{\"{pp.Key}\":\"{pp.Value.Raw}\"}}")) + "]}"));
        }
    }
}

public class ProductProperty
{
    [JsonProperty("raw")]
    public string Raw { get; set; }
}
}
```

Output:
[image]